# activemq deny remote connections

Tags: maven, activemq-classic

I am trying to run ActiveMQ with Maven using the following command

```
mvn org.apache.activemq.tooling:maven-activemq-plugin:5.7.0:run
```

This does work locally, but it blocks remote connections. How can I make ActiveMQ accept remote connections?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding to Aksel Willgrets answer.

You need a custom conf (somethings like the deafult activemq xml config that ships with the stand alone dist).

[This](http://activemq.apache.org/maven2-activemq-broker-plugin.html) page documents the maven plugin, read it.

```
 <build>    
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq.tooling</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>5.8.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <configUri>xbean:file:../conf/activemq.xml</configUri>
          .. etc.
```

That activemq.xml should point out a transport connector (see Aksel Willgerts answer or use the default xml file from ActiveMQ).

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure your broker for remote [transport](http://activemq.apache.org/configuring-transports.html).

if you are using a broker.xml config-file, tcp transport could be configured like this:

```
<transportConnectors>
  <transportConnector uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616"/>
</transportConnectors>
```